# Android Studio sync error with GoogleMaps

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, build.gradle

When I try to sync my android project it gives me the following error message.

[image]

When I click on the link to upgrade it shows

[image]

Here are the dependencies which I have added to build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Libraries
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:design:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:fairebase-ui-database:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:fairebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gsm:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSerachBar:0.8.2'

    //RxJava2
    implementatiom 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementatiom 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'

    //Retrofit2
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    implementation 'io.paperdb"paperdb:2.6'
```

I'm doing this with the help of a youtube video. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import in the root build.gradle google services?

You can also start a new project with Google Maps and compare the dependencies